# Elimination of Trend and Seasonality Using Classical Decomposition Model

Tags: time-series, self-study, seasonality, trend, decomposition

Brockwell and Davis (2016, page 26) have illustrated the classical decomposition model for elimination of trend and seasonality.

the assumptions for this model are:

$X_{t} = m_{t} + s_{t} + Y_{t}, t = 1, 2, ...., n,$

where $EY_{t} = 0 (ASM.1), S_{t+d} = S_{t}(ASM.2)$, and $\sum_{j=1}^ds_{j} = 0(ASM.3)$

In the second step, they have illustrated how they removed seasonality:

> The second step is to estimate the seasonal component.  For each $k =
> 1,... , d$ we compute the average $w_{k}$ of the deviations 
>   ${(x_{k+jd} − \hat{m}_{k+jd}), q < k + jd ≤ n − q}$. Since these average deviations do not
>   necessarily sum to zero, we estimate the seasonal component $s_{k}$ as
>
> $\hat{s}_{k} = w_{k} − d^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^dw_{i}$, $k = 1,... , d, $
>   (1.5.13)
>
> and $\hat{s}_{k} = \hat{s}_{k}−d, k > d$

I am a bit confused with their notations:

1. how shall I interpret the term $w_{k}$, is that single term or is it a summation? if it is the average of **deviations**, i.e

   $w_{k}=d^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^dw_{k}$

   which implies that $k = i$ and therefore satisfies $ASM.3$ above?
2. for example when $j=2$, $d=2$, $k=1$ then, 
   $X_{k+jd} = X_{1+2\times2} = X_{5}$. if $j$ means year, $k$ means month, is this the correct indexing method? i.e. shouldn't the point in time for 2nd month in 2nd year  be $X_{2+2} = X_{4}$?
3. why do we need to have the condition of $q < k+jd < n-q$, where either
   $d = 2q$ or $d = 2q + 1$?

sincerely appreciate any guidance.